# Keep getting 404 error for axios call (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

I keep getting a 404 error even though my routes should be correct. I have refreshed my cache/routes, and made sure that the epHash and fileHash are correct. It is getting to the PHP function, as I made it make a text file right before it declares $file.

##### The PHP

```php
public function deleteFile($epHash, $fileHash) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!Auth::check() || !$user->is_admin) {
            abort(500);
        }

        $file = File::findOrFail($fileHash);

        Storage::delete($file->path . $file->name);
        $file->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'advisors' => Advisor::with([
                "user.person.contactInfo",
                "clients",
                "clients.person.contactInfo",
                "clients.spouse",
                "clients.estatePlans",
                "clients.estatePlans.files",
                "user.person",
                "clients.estatePlans.files.createdBy"
            ])->get(),
        ]);
    }
```

##### The Route

```php
Route::delete('/api/estatePlan/{epHash}/{fileHash}/delete', [Controllers\ClientInfoController::class, 'deleteFile']);
```

##### The JavaScript

```js
deleteFile(epHash, fileHash) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: "Are you sure you want to delete this file?",
                icon: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                cancelButtonText: "No",
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    axios
                        .delete(`/api/estatePlan/${epHash}/${fileHash}/delete`)
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log("DELETED FILE SUCCESSFULLY");
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error.response);
                        });
                }
            });
        },
```

I was expecting to have the call go through, I have checked my laravel logs and nothing as well.

Comment: Why do you have it defined as `/api` in your route? is it inside `web.php` or `api.php`? if it is `api.php`, then the final url is `/api/api/...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel as an API, you should define your route inside the api.php file included in the routes folder, without adding /api to the defined route (it is added automatically), so it would be like:

```
Route::delete('/estatePlan/{epHash}/{fileHash}/delete', [Controllers\ClientInfoController::class, 'deleteFile']);
```

Clear your cache and check if your route is shown in the list of routes by executing the **php artisan route:list** command.

When calling your route, make sure you also include the domain where Laravel is hosted in the URL.
Then, you can call your route from javascript using the following URL (considering a local environment where Laravel is hosted on localhost:8000):

```
http://localhost:8000/api/estatePlan/${epHash}/${fileHash}/delete
```

Do not forget to start your server using **php artisan serve**.